# Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk custom variables in batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We use AWS Elastic Beanstalk for an application, each application has three environments test, uat and prod.

The problem we're facing is that every time an application activates the scaling options we lose the application logs when the scaling cools down.

While we rewrite our application to ship it's logs to a syslog service we require an interim solution which is a batch script deployed via ebextensions.

Part of the batch script is to schedule a task to run it daily (for now) but we're unable to pass in the custom variables supplied by AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

**Example:**

```
schtasks /create /SC daily /ST 00:00:00 /f /TN s3sync /TR "c:\s3sync.bat {PARAM2}"
```

We've tried using *container_commands* with zero luck.

**Example:**

```
02_schedule_s3sync:
  command: "c:\\s3sync.bat {$PARAM2}"
```

Any advice, alternate methods or a solution would be most helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I clean forgot about this question so I though I would update it with the correct answer for anybody stuck with the same issue.

`02_schedule_s3sync:
  command: schtasks /create /sc hourly /st 00:00:00 /f /ru System /tn s3sync /tr "C:\s3sync.bat %PARAM2% %PARAM3% %PARAM4%" /v1`

Comment: Did this work, from what I have seen the Environment variables specified in the Beanstalk configuration are not exposed as EC2 Environment variables.  I opened up a CMD prompt and used 'set' and did not see the values.  After some research, I found a parent web.config in the  c:\inetpub\wwwroot directory that held the values.  So, they apparently are only available as  .net configuration values (in my case).   I want to do what you suggest, have not tried it yet, but appears that it will not work.  Any update on this?

Comment: Update: I tried a 'command' using an assigned environment variable and it did not work.   Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Update: It does work, but only if you are using the 'container_commands'.  I was using initially the 'commands'.   The documentation on the config container_commands affirms this, it does say that the environment variables are present.   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Custom Environment Properties are available only inside the container. After you set these properties, they become available to your AWS Elastic Beanstalk application as system properties.

They are not available directly on EC2 instance.

Since it is just for a workaround, one option would be to add an API to your application to return parameter value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Mentioning the API triggered a light bulb moment. Although I didn't end up using the API I did however end up using powershell to get what I required.